# What is the regular expression to match all files that end on ".txt" using std::regex or boost::regex libraries?

Tags: c++, regex, std

I am lopping through some directory and want to print all files that end with .txt. This  code doesn't work.
ft::FilePath filePath;
std::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator iter(m_rootDirectoryPath);

```
    const std::regex e("*.txt");

    for(;iter != std::filesystem::end(iter); ++iter)
    {
        if(std::regex_match(iter->path().string(),e))
        {
            const std::string& p = iter->path().string();
            uint64_t pos = p.find(m_rootDirectoryPath.string());
            filePath.set_path(p.substr(pos + m_rootDirectoryPath.string().size()));
            writer->Write(filePath);
        }
    }
```

**What is the regular expression to match all files that end with .txt?** (you must assume that I use std::regex to match patterns)

Comment: Off topic but... if the pattern *is* that simple it might be better to use [`std::filesystem::path::extension`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/extension) rather than a regex.

Comment: Yea, but I am writing function that returns vector of files that match a specific regular expression. I just wanted to test this function, but I don't know regex at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi the regex that you are looking for is `R"(.*\.txt$)"`

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <regex>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    const std::regex e{R"(.*\.txt)"};
    const std::vector<std::string> files{{"toto.txt", "titi.doc", "tata.txt", "txt"}};

    for(const auto& str : files)
    {
        if(std::regex_match(str, e))
        {
            std::cout << str << '\n';
        }
    }
    
    std::cout.flush();
}
```

note that:

- you can test regex with the following site: https://regex101.com
- if you are in C++20 you can use [`ends_with`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/ends_with)
- filesystem path has a method [`extension`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/extension)

Comment: No it a C++11 syntax link to the `R` that allow to avoid double \

Answer (score 1):

```
".*\\.txt$"
```

Your expression is a glob used in shells.